# setText returning error when attempting to input a string on an editText Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, settext

I am attempting to perform a simple mathematical operation on one editText field which changes the value of another editText field (a unit conversion calculator).

```
 inchesEditText.setText(String) = (metersVal.toString().toDouble() * metersToInchesVal).toString()
```

The following error was returned when setting the text of the editText field:

> Error:(24, 28) None of the following functions can be called with the
>   arguments supplied: public final fun setText(p0: CharSequence!): Unit
>   defined in android.widget.EditText public final fun setText(p0: Int):
>   Unit defined in android.widget.EditText

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Instead of `inchesEditText.setText(String) = ` use `inchesEditText.text = ` or just pass the value on the right hand side to the setText() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do something like below. If you want to set value in EditText then you have to set value inside `yourEditText.setText('yourvalue')` and `yourvalue` must be in `String` format. check below,

```
inchesEditText.setText( (metersVal.toString().toDouble() * metersToInchesVal).toString() )
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you can write in below way :

```
mBinding.txtHandlerTimer.text = (metersVal.toString().toDouble() * metersToInchesVal).toString()
```

Thanks